# How can I get a URI from ApexCharts to download in PDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, jspdf, apexcharts

I already implemented an ApexCharts and want to output it into a PDF document.

I tried to get a download URI from `chart.dataURI`, but it failed with an error:

> chart.dataURI is not a function

Below is the creation of the Apex bar graph and my attempt with the download URI, but it does not fetch:

```js
var options = {
  chart: {
    height: 450,
    type: 'bar',
    width: 1000,
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      horizontal: false,
      columnWidth: '40%',
      endingShape: 'rounded'
    },
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  colors: ['#008000', '#d4a823', '#f92525'],
  stroke: {
    show: true,
    width: 2,
    colors: ['transparent']
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Good',
    data: JSON.stringify(graph_data.good)
  }, {
    name: 'Okey',
    data: JSON.stringify(graph_data.ok)
  }, {
    name: 'Bad',
    data: JSON.stringify(graph_data.bad)
  }],
  xaxis: {
    categories: graph_data.month,
  },
  yaxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Smiley Percentage'
    }
  },
  fill: {
    opacity: 1

  },
  tooltip: {
    y: {
      formatter: function(val) {
        return val + " Smileys"
      }
    }
  }
}

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#monthlyhistory"), options);
var dataURL = chart.dataURI().then((uri) => {  // Here shows an error
  console.log(uri);
  var pdf = new jsPDF();
  pdf.addImage(uri, 'PNG', 0, 0);
  pdf.save("download.pdf");
})}
```

I expect the output in PDF format, but it is not working.

Comment: Reformat code into a code block. Changed and corrected text as much as I could understand the question.

Comment: Léa Gris it's corrected now graph is created but for download its gives error when fetching uri

Comment: I did not change your code functioning, just reformatted your question so it was more understandable and give you more chance to get help for your PDF output.

Comment: Léa Gris yes i removed some code for creation of chart becuase due to that it was created two times Please help me to sort out this error i can't fetch the uri of chart recieving this error chart.dataURI is not a function

Comment: **Can Anyone Help me out of this issue**

Answer (score 5):

Below is a solution with some additional code that helps us to render the chart to fit nicely within the frame of the pdf file.
My previous attempts did render the chart but the chart did not fill the page with nasty white uneven borders to the side and bottom.

The 'chart' reference is based upon getting the actual instance of th current chart once rendered...

Dont forget to load the jsPDF library in the header section of the web page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

I call the function below from a button along the navbar just above the div element where I render the chart. Note I called the div element a 'chartCanvas' but it's not actually a canvas element, it's just a div with my own class parameters.

```
function downloadChartToPdf() {
    if (chart) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("chartCanvas");
        var width = canvas.clientWidth;
        var height = canvas.clientHeight;
        console.log(width); // testing only...
        console.log(height); // testing only...
        // ----- Not currently in use... -----
        //var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        //console.log(rect.width); // testing only...
        //console.log(rect.height); // testing only...
        // -------------------------------------------

        chart.dataURI().then(({ imgURI, blob }) => {
            //set the orientation
            if (width > height) {
                console.log("landscape"); // testing only...
                let pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'px', [width, height]);
                pdf.backgroundColor = '#BFBFBF';
                //then we get the dimensions from the 'pdf' file itself
                width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
                height = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
                widthWithPadding = width - 20;
                heightWithPadding = height - 20;
                pdf.addImage(imgURI, 'PNG', 10, 10, widthWithPadding, heightWithPadding);
                pdf.save("chart.pdf");
            }
            else {
                console.log("portrait"); // testing only...
                let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'px', [height, width]);
                pdf.backgroundColor = '#BFBFBF';
                //then we get the dimensions from the 'pdf' file itself
                width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
                height = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
                widthWithPadding = width - 20;
                heightWithPadding = height - 20;
                pdf.addImage(imgURI, 'PNG', 10, 10, widthWithPadding, heightWithPadding);
                pdf.save("chart.pdf");
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Exported PDF result:

[image]

Comment: This is working, but let's say your chart is inside chartCanvas div which has some elements and  special styling as a card, so, you want to export the chartCanvas as a card contain the chart+special elements, how do you do that?

Answer (score 3):

Before calling the `chart.dataURI()` function, you need to render the chart (which I cannot find in your question)

The `render` function returns a promise, so you can chain any additional code in the `then()` handler of it.

Like this.

```js
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render().then(() => {
    chart.dataURI().then(({ imgURI, blob }) => { 
        var pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.addImage(imgURI, 'PNG', 0, 0);
        pdf.save("download.pdf");
    })
})
```

Here is the working [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/JjPZPNb)

Comment: Yes its work the same by dummy data as you did in codepen demo i know i have some issue i am trying if i can't i will view the whole code here                                                               Thank you you elaborate it more for me thanks

Comment: Thanks Dear It works for me i make the answer useful but i don't have 50 reputations that's why answer count is not increment